# How to get selected messages in groupwise add in

Tags: interop, add-in, groupwise

I am trying to get selected messages from GroupWise client add in. 
previously our code to get it was working fine using C3POManager with GroupWise version 8, but with new GroupWise version 2014 it has stopped working.

previously working code as below

```
 Dim oSelectedMessages As Object = C3POManager.ClientState.SelectedMessages
 If oSelectedMessages.Count > 0 Then
    sMessageID = oSelectedMessages(1).MessageID
 End If
```

now with GroupWise 2014 oSelectedMessages is Nothing (null).

I have tried searching on internet and also tried looking at Novell's documentation but couldn't find any suitable solution.

can any one suggest what is changed by groupwise or how to overcome this issue.

Thanks,

Tank

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be using an obsolete version of the C3PO objects. Make sure you have the latest [Groupwise SDK](https://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/groupwise/groupwise_c3po.html).

There is also the [Groupwise C3PO support](https://forums.novell.com/forumdisplay.php/811-DEV-GroupWise-C3PO) forum.